# Client A change source mac address to Client B when send packet, But Client B's module can not rx packet after server sent

Tags: linux, network-programming, mac-address, ipv4, netfilter

I have 3 host:

Client A

Client B

Server.

I have below test scenario:

Client A send raw packet to server (change source mac address to Client B's)

Server reply this packet (I use tcpdump to make sure Server have replied this packet)

Client B install one module that register hook function on netfilter pre-routing, But nothing reveived.

Does anybody know why Client B's hook function receive nothing?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your switch has seen client B's MAC address on the port to client A and has remembered that. It will therefore send the reply on the ethernet port to client A, not to client B's erhernet port.

This seems to be a networking issue, not a programming issue. Therefore this question might be more appropriate on a different forum.

Answer (score 0):

There's an ARP cache on the server side, probably it already contains an association between host A and original MAC of host A (I guess this association appears when client A establishes connection with the server).

```
arp -n
```

will show the content of the ARP table.
Each ARP table entry has some expiration timeout. When it expires, server tries to refresh the expired entry by sending ARP who-has requests to all hosts in local network. So only after cache entry of host A expires, the server absorbs updated information.

Comment: ARP has nothing to do with this, the OP is generating raw Ethernet packets.